# How can I filter more than once on Firebase dashboard?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I have some custom events and user properties (Firebase Analytics).
I can filter by one of them on the dashboard, and see useful information.

But how can I have multiple filters active at once? So far I can only see how to have one, which is almost useless. I don't fancy using *BigQuery*, it sounds much more complicated than I need. I just want a few filters.

Comment: Did you figure something out @xaphod?

Comment: nope :( I can't believe this basic functionality isn't there. I'm using Fabric now. Which google just bought...

Comment: I bet Fabric will end up integrated within Firebase... Does Fabric allow you to filter your data on multiple dimensions? I'm trying to run experiments, so I have a couple dimensions and a couple metrics (outcomes) I'm measuring; but there doesn't seem to be a way to get a clean table of numbers from that (with dimensions as rows and metrics as columns).

Comment: No fabric doesn't allow the filtering i want, but it does show a ton more useful information

Comment: As an alternative service, I can suggest [Yandex AppMetrica](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru). It provide an ability for multi-dimensional filtering, plus shows events with a short time lag (near 5-15 minutes). Not sure about its ability to automatically track in-app purchases or revenue (perhaps no) but for events and crashes this service is really good